# Migration problems using Django 1.9

Tags: windows, command-prompt, python-3.4, atom-editor, django-1.9

I am currently programming in Django (1.9), Python (3.4) and using the atom code editor. I am trying to program my first website.

I am programming `python manage.py migrate` in window command prompt and the following error keeps coming up:
     [image]

What do I define in the templates settings? What is meant by 'pass the callable instead'?

Answer (score 0):

those are just warnings and not errors it seems.

For first warning - about templates, when you generate the project the proper way through `manage.py startproject` it should generate sample `settings.py` and `urls.py` for you. Try reading through tutorial here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01. Here is example how you can define templates in your settings.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings

For second warning - it seems that you are pasing the string `'Bussiness.views.home'`, that is fine for now, like I said, it's just a warning. But to get rid of the warning, simply put directly the function instead of the string.

example in your `urls.py`

```
from myapp import views as myapp_views  # as myapp_views to prevent further colisions 
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', myapp_views.home)
]
```